# Create a new column based on result of other

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame("ref" = c("A","A","B","B","C","C","C"),
                 "trans" = c("R","MTA","N","MTA","MTA","MTA","MTA"))

  ref trans
1   A     R
2   A   MTA
3   B     N
4   B   MTA
5   C   MTA
6   C   MTA
7   C   MTA
```

I want to create a new column which picks out the value "R" or "N" for each reference and repeats it for every row. If the values "R" or "N" do not exist then the column should simple have values of "N" everywhere.

I tried something like this:

```
df %>% group_by (ref,trans) %>% arrange(desc(ref), desc(trans)) %>% mutate(result = trans[1L])
```

but doesnt work. (note the group by is required as my dataset is more granular).

The result should be

```
  ref trans result
1   A     R      R
2   A   MTA      R
3   B     N      N
4   B   MTA      N
5   C   MTA      N
6   C   MTA      N
7   C   MTA      N
```

solution in dplyr preferable

Answer (score 2):

Using `case_when` inside `mutate` will work for the example you've provided.  Are there no `ref`s though that have `"R"` and `"N"`?

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ref) %>% 
  mutate(result = case_when(any(trans == "R") ~ "R",
                            any(trans == "N") ~ "N",
                            TRUE ~ "N"))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   ref [3]
  ref   trans result
  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 A     R     R     
2 A     MTA   R     
3 B     N     N     
4 B     MTA   N     
5 C     MTA   N     
6 C     MTA   N     
7 C     MTA   N
```

Comment: How would I check if there any refs that have both R and N? Could you also explain what "~" does

Comment: @user33484 The tilde (~) in this case means "set to", reading in words "in a case where any value of trans equals R set result to R".

Comment: and TRUE ~ "N" means anything else set to "N"?

Comment: @user33484 correct, because `case_when` evaluates whatever is to the left of the tidle, and if that left hand side is true it does the right hand side (much like `ifelse`).  In that particular line of code I'm just setting the left hand side to `TRUE` explicitly

Comment: thanks that makes sense. If I wanted to find out which value of "ref" column had only "MTA" values (and no "R" or "N" values) how would I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Could try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ref) %>%
  mutate(result = c('N', 'R')[any(trans == 'R') + 1])
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   ref [3]
  ref   trans result
  <fct> <fct> <chr> 
1 A     R     R     
2 A     MTA   R     
3 B     N     N     
4 B     MTA   N     
5 C     MTA   N     
6 C     MTA   N     
7 C     MTA   N
```

Comment: could you explain that code here, wher exactly is c('N','R')[...] doing? Sorry never seen this before

Comment: It's a shortened version of `ifelse`, i.e. it checks if any `trans` equals `R`, if yes then assigns `R` else `N`.

Comment: It's actually safer than `ifelse` in one regard: notice the difference between `ifelse(c(T,T), 1, "a")` (num) and `ifelse(c(T,F), 1, "a")` (chr), and then this equivalent with `c("a",1)[c(T,T)+1]` (chr) versus `c("a",1)[c(T,F)+1]` (again, chr). I consider `ifelse`'s approach unsafe in that it may not return the class one expects, whereas it is less surprising (*to me*) that `c("a",1)` is always all `character`.